# object linking consistency over network with binary serialisation

Tags: c#, networking, serialization

I'm asking for more of an explanation more than anything about c# objects.

```
[Serializable]
class ExampleSub
{
    public Example parent;
    public ExampleSub(Example parent)
    {
        this.parent= parent;
    }
}
[Serializable]
class Example
{
    List<ExampleSub> subs;
    public Example()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            subs.Add(new ExampleSub(this));
    }
}
```

If I was to binary-serialise the Example class, with it containing the ExampleSubs in the list. Then sent it over a TCP connection, where on the other end it was deserialised back into an Example object. Would the ExampleSub's parent object point at the new Example object (as it should).

My question mostly is revolving around how the serialiser correctly maps the objects together, but also about how c# objects are identified at all really since the closest I can guess is that they act like smart-pointers.